# Detect single-user mode from the command line

Tags: command-line

Is there a way to detect single-user mode in OSX (Lion, specifically) from the command line?

I've tried `who -r`, which returns `3` in either standard or single-user mode.

I've also tried `nvram boot-args`, which does not work either.

Google isn't helping much with this...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ sysctl -n kern.singleuser
0
```

It's **1** when booted in single-user mode, **0** when not.

Comment: Confirmed - thanks, Ingmar, just what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm. We don't have runlevel in OS X*, which would be the easy way. How about identifying something in the output of `launchctl list` which is not present in single user mode but is present otherwise - `com.apple.Finder` might be a candidate.

*`man who` includes: `-r    Print the current runlevel.  This is meaningless on Mac OS X.`

Comment: Thanks, Adam - thought I'd try `who` anyway to confirm. As for `launchctl list`, it returns a `Socket is not connected` error when in Single User Mode...I wonder if that is enough of a hook?

Comment: Finder isn't always running even in 'normal mode'. It can be quit or replaced with another launcher.

Comment: If that's consistent Scot, it might be very convenient!

Answer (score 1):

In single user mode open directory is not available except by jumping through hoops. You can test the return value of dscl in that case.